# java operator and exclusive with boolean operands

Tags: java

can anyone tell me why it prints out 1?
I know for sure that true and false AND EXCLUSIVE gives 0. why it enters in if statement?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean a=true, b=false; 
    int i=0; 
    if(a^b)   {
        i++;
    } 
    System.out.print(i++);
 }
```

thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646514/what-are-xand-and-xor

Comment: Actually it is XOR aka OR EXCLUSIVE, which gives true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using xor : `^`.

```
true ^ false == true
```

See also:

- [Is it good practice to use the XOR (^) operator in Java for boolean checks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/160697/521799)
- [Creating a "logical exclusive or" operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/726652/521799)

I'm actually not sure what you mean by "exclusive and". See also:

- [What are XAND and XOR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2646514/521799)

Comment: But I learnt that XOR gives true only when we have 1 and 1 (true , true) , but in this case we have 1 and 0 (false). isn't?

Comment: That's just "AND". As in `&&` or `&`

Comment: `T && T == T`, `T && F == F`, `T ^ T == F`, `T ^ F == T`

Answer (score 2):

xor tables

```
0^0 == 0
0^1 == 1
1^0 == 1
1^1 == 0
```

So it enters the if statement.

At the end of your main block, after the `System.out.println(i++)` the `i` variable will have the value `2` as currently written

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about `^`, it is exclusive *or*. And for any propositions p1 and p2, p1 ^ p2 is true *only if one of p1 or p2 are true*.

It is therefore normal that it prints 1.

Answer (score 0):

In Java the `^` operator is bitwise Exclusive OR, not Exclusive AND. Since `true XOR false` is TRUE, it enters in the if clause.

I'd suggest for you simply to use `==` and `!=` operators, if you're dealing with `boolean`.

Comment: In this context it is not the bitwise exclusive or, but the logical exclusive or ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `^` operator is [exclusive *or*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). The truth table for this is

```
 XOR  | false true 
-------------------
false | false true
true  | true  false
```

That's why you get "1" - your `if` statement evaluates to true.

Cheers,